# Redirect Visual Studio to new TFS Location

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

We have migrated TFS from one server to another. I have verified that the source files and history do exist in the new server location.

How do I now redirect Visual Studio to look at the new server location? I would like to not lose any of the files, history and to realize pending changes, etc.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to connect to the new TFS from Team, Connect to Team Foundation Server menu.

Comment: And then choose 'Select Team Projects'. 
You probably will have to adjust your workspace to.